# Parse the hexadecimal string to XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, hex

My code

```cs
string workflowIdRef="WorkflowUser_NEW B&#xEC;nh Thu&#x1EAD;n Copy"
string requestFileXml = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Admin/TS/requestXml/JobCreateReq.xml");
XmlDocument xmld = new XmlDocument();
xmld.Load(requestFileXml);
string requestXml = xmld.OuterXml;              
requestXml = requestXml.Replace("WORKFLOW_ID", workflowIdRef);

//Parse string requestXml to xDocument Temp
 XDocument xTemp = XDocument.Parse(requestXml);
```

I debug and see below result

Text Visualizer mode:

[image]

And XML visualizer:

[image]

The `XDocument` `XTemp` has result string like in the picture 2

How to get `XTemp` to have result string like in the picture 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is special character in XML, it's a marker for beginning of an encoded character like `&#xEC;`. If you want it as plain string as opposed to encoded character you'll need to escape `&` by using `&amp;`, for example `&amp;#xEC;`.

**demo :**

```cs
//notice that & are escaped to &amp; in the following string :
string workflowIdRef="WorkflowUser_NEW B&amp;#xEC;nh Thu&amp;#x1EAD;n Copy"

string workflowIdRef = "WorkflowUser_NEW B&amp;#xEC;nh Thu&amp;#x1EAD;n Copy";
string xmlContent = @"<root workflowIdRef=""WORKFLOW_ID""/>";
xmlContent.Replace("WORKFLOW_ID", workflowIdRef);.Replace("WORKFLOW_ID", workflowIdRef);

XDocument xTemp = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
```

**output :**

[image]